# Table row and colgroup border issues

Tags: javascript, html, css-tables

I have a table ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xAE68/1/)) which has some javascript that applies a `hover` class to the appropriate colgroup and row when mouse over occurs.  This should display as a `+` within the table i.e. the column is highlighted, and the row is.

Unfortunately with borders applied ([second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xAE68/)) this goes a bit screwy once you mouseover a few cells (I'm looking in Chrome).  Can anyone see why this is happening?

I've tried commenting out the `border-collpase` property but this hasn't worked.

```
.hover {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    background: #f4f4f4;
}
colgroup.hover {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
tr.hover{
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment last two css property as you shown in fiddle1

```
/*colgroup.hover {
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
tr.hover{
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}*/
```

Comment: If you do that (see second fiddle) then after a number of hovers (wiggle mouse around on screen) you start to see visual artefacts and it doesnt work.

Comment: replace css of fiddle2 by fiddle1 , and see that @Chris

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix. Try adding these rules.

```
colgroup {
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}


tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

The reason you are having weird effects is because the borders are changing the dimensions of the boxes.

By adding white borders (or ones that match the backing), you are simply changing the colors without changing the dimensions.

EDIT:

You can change the rules in under hover to change the border-color if you'd like. That will eliminate some redundancies.